# Coppers Pours for 4-Layer RF (433MHz) Board?

Tags: rf, pcb-design, pcb-layers, copper-pour

I've got a 4-layer prototype transmitter board built that is using a low-speed MCU (2 MHz).  The critical RF sections are 50 ohm impedance matched to the board's characteristics. I eliminated the GND plane under the antenna and did some via shielding.

The board is just a traditional 4 layer stackup. Top Layer | GND | VDD | Bottom Layer. So in the first run of the board, signals are traced on the outer layers, and then I used vias to connect to the GND & VDD layers. I did not use any copper pours on any outer layer.

Overall the signal strength of my prototype board vs. the manufacturer demo module is largely the same.

However, the TX board is going to go into an enclosure so any increase in transmission strength from board layout is going to be a benefit.

I've got to do another turn of the board for some layout corrections, and I can't decide if it is worth flooding the outer layers with copper pours.

On one hand, you have the potential EMI reduction benefits.  I've had the board FCC tested at a qualified lab for Part 15, but not for any applicable EMI type testing yet.  I'm assuming I am compliant...  if not, okay sure copper pours. But that is not my main concern.

At 433 MHz, antenna manufacturers (Linx Technologies) specify 6 inches by 6 inches for an "ideal" GND plane for a 1/4 wavelength antenna.  Clearly, I don't have that kind of space on my board.

As this is a cheap consumer product, we are using low cost metal helical antennas.  If you examine one of these antennas with a VNA, they do not have great center frequency responses (+/- a few MHZ) and have pretty poor SWR across 433mhz.  The upside -- they are cheap and compact.  Any increased antenna performance, I could eek out with a board change is basically just low hanging fruit.

Do you "get" a larger GND plane by flooding the outer layer with a GND plane and then tying it with vias back to the GND plane?  Would you get some benefit there for better antenna performance with a larger GND plane?

On the other hand, I've read that a copper pour on the outer layers can influence trace impedance? The TX IC I am using, comes with a matching network to turn the TX output signal to 50ohms.  If you adjusted the trace impedance with the copper pour, the IC manufacturer does not provide details on their TX IC & matching network where you could easily readjust their matching network. So that seems like a potential source of signal attenuation.

Also on the negative side, I've read there is a potential for creating antennas for stray pieces of the GND plane that aren't tied through vias.  Assuming you know what you are doing, you can control for this and tie all the copper back to the internal GND plane with vias?

I read one ATMEL app note, and they noted copper pours on 4-layer RF boards as questionable practice for anything but EMI purposes. In their example they put a copper pour on the top layer with all the RF comoponents and traces, and then just loaded up the board with via stiching (30mil pattern) wherever the copper pour was present.

Is there anyone here who has built a 4 layer RF board, who has ever seen a performance boost by implementing GND pours on both outer layers?

Most application notes typically infer a user is using a 2 layer board, where the benefits are more clear.  I've seen this debated each way, and am wondering if someone can speak from experience with a RF 4-layer board?

Comment: I don't believe you are using a CPU with a 0.002 Hz clock. There is a very large difference between 2 mHz and 2 MHz.

Comment: Haha.  Very clever catch.  For all effective purposes, I don't think 2mHz or 2MHz is going to qualify as a high speed board...

Comment: Is one of your inner layers being used as a ground plane?

Comment: Hi -- yes, sorry I should clarify that.  It is just a traditional 4 layer stackup.  Top Layer | GND | VDD | Bottom Layer.  So in the first run of the board, signals are traced on the outer layers, and then I used vias to connect to the GND & VDD layers.

Comment: Why would you mount a 1/4 wave antenna directly on your board? I'd either use an antenna connector to an external chassis-mounted 1/4 antenna, or go for 1/2 wave. Unless of course, you do have lots of board space.

Comment: Hi -- the quick answer for the 1/4 wave antenna is that there is an existing enclosure (read: a mold in a factory I own) being re-used for this project.  At 433MHz, a 1/4 wave is ~6.7inches and a 1/2 wave is ~13.4inches! This is a consumer product, not an army walkie-talkie...  433/315 MHz is like your garage opener and short distance transmitters.  For perspective, we have another design in a different frequency in the same enclosure that goes 2000 meters.  FCC limits 433 MHz pretty strictly, with this particular TX IC with an external 1/4 antenna you are probably way out of the FCC limits.

Comment: @Leroy105 Well there exist chip antennas for 433MHz but they aren't very good. As for using 433MHz in USA, you might want to read [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/293639/north-american-regulations-on-433mhz-radio/293781#293781). You are developing a "commercial container identification system"?

Comment: @Lundin -- I don't know what section that is, but see the"you will have to apply for a license with FCC" portion.  You have to go through regulatory testing for Part 15 (and whatever other subsections... I'm not an expert).  It appears there is some odd carve-out where you DON'T have to get an FCC license for shipping containers.  Odd.  We've already been through pre-regulatory scanning to determine the FCC limit so we can do "relative" readings on lab equipment on prototypes. If you could only use 433MHz for this limited purpose, why do so many large IC manufacturers develop chips for 433MHz?

Comment: @Lundin -- at lunch I looked at that section you mentioned, it seems limiting, but at the same time the FCC is [granting 433MHz FCC IDs](https://apps.fcc.gov/oetcf/tcb/reports/Tcb731GrantForm.cfm?mode=COPY&RequestTimeout=500&tcb_code=&application_id=LMirK%2BmdzV2zLwO10bg9wQ%3D%3D&fcc_id=2AJAQ-LLR01).  So I'm not certain what the carve-out in the regulations is, but low power transmitters evidently are okay.

Comment: @Lundin -- I had to ask our regulatory engineer, but here is the deal:  Your link refers to operation under FCC Part 15.240.  Operation under the provisions of FCC Part 15.231 is allowed at 433.92MHz.  Operating conditions are quite different under those two rule parts.

Comment: @Leroy105 You are misunderstanding the meaning of license. License = allowance to use a specific device in a limited geographic area, which typically comes with a fee and FCC registration per device. What you speak of is FCC _approval_ which is another thing but mandatory too. Part 15 is generally about bands that don't need a license.

Comment: [15.231](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=09cbfc8649c7916ed41d0636a252850d&mc=true&node=se47.1.15_1231&rgn=div8) means that you have to use periodic transmission."A manually operated transmitter shall employ a switch that will automatically deactivate the transmitter within not more than 5 seconds of being released." If that's ok for your application then yeah you could use that band. Also note the weird FCC uV/m requirement of output power.

Comment: @Lundin -- so going back to my original post, WHERE I NEVER ASKED ABOUT ANTENNAS OR FCC REGULATIONS...?  It is about a very specific board layout question for a 4 layer RF board...

Comment: @Leroy105 Hence comments not answers. I'm a radio firmware person so I don't dabble with layouts in general. From my experience, yeah I'd say copper pour on all layers is common, with lots of vias everywhere. But you shouldn't ask me, ask a RF layout person :)

Comment: @Lundin -- I am finishing up the CRC, forward error correction & manchesterizing, routines as we speak on the TX.... RX is 4x oversampled with a clock recovery scheme.